# make: *** [Core/Src/subdir.mk:34: Core/Src/main.o] Error 1

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stm32, libraries, mcu

I am a newbie for STM32. After activating all my peripheral libraries I try to build my code but I get the following error:

> make: *** [Core/Src/subdir.mk:34: Core/Src/main.o] Error 1
>
> "make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

I am using a `STM32F411` board.

Has anybody dealt with this issue?

Comment: It looks like a command executed by your Makefile (likely your compiler) failed. Can you post the full output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Everyone of us dealt with this error, that is, all of us using "make". :-D -- The message you show is the last one, and "make" is telling you that _something_ went wrong as it called other commands. One of these commands reported an error, which is the real issue. Please show us all error messages. In general, commonly only the _first_ message is the relevant one. The following messages are mostly just consequences of this first error.

Comment: Thanks! I get the error on the TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM8, &TIM_InitStructure); command, then this is the first error I get:  n file included from ../Core/Src/main.c:4:
D:/STM32/STM32CubeIDE_1.7.0/STM32CubeIDE/STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/stm32f4xx_rcc.h:65: warning: "RCC_HSE_OFF" redefined
   65 | #define RCC_HSE_OFF                      ((uint8_t)0x00)

Comment: The new includes i've added are the following libraries: #include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_adc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_tim.h"